# is TS5 connector the same as crc9 connector? IF yes then why do they have 2 names. which connector is present in huawei e8372 4g usb modem?

Tags: usb, modem

Totally confused about ts5 and crc9 connectors. How are they different ?. who invented them and what is the correct technical name -- ts5 or crc9 ?. Are they part of any relevant standards?. which connector is present in huawei 4G modems [e.g. E8372]? .please someone put some light over my dark mind.

Comment: @paul sure I did, but this page https://consumer.huawei.com/en/mobile-broadband/e8372/specs/   mentions EXTERNAL ANTENNA INTERFACE as 
TS-5, so I am confused that are ts5 and crc9 connectors the same or not?. are there any technical standards for them. could not find on googling.

Answer (score 2):

The link that @paul references doesn't contain ts-5 (or ts5) but at https://www.4glte.eu/en/38-crc-9-ts-5-connector it sure looks like TS-5 is the same as CRC-9. Ditto at https://www.amazon.co.uk/Connector-Adapter-External-Antenna-Hotspot-Black/dp/B06XF9STHX.

Comment: that's what I also think  and as quoted in this manufacturers blog, https://halberdbastion.com/resources/hardware/rf-connectors/rf-connector-series/crc9,         
  ". Design and production of the CRC9 connector does not follow any defined international standard, nor does the design follow a proprietary specification, Used almost exclusively on Chinese manufactured devices".                                                but I sure think the chinese must have copied it from some prevalent standard.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good summary for RF connectors but only TS9 and CRC9 are mentioned: https://specialistantennas.blogspot.com/2013/05/the-10-most-comon-rf-coaxial-connectors.html

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not post link only answers as the linked site might change or be removed entirely, rendering your answer useless. Instead quote the most important parts from the site and provide the link as reference only.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1119137)